# Publish a dynamic form on sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, asp.net, microsoft-forms

I have to create a form (a request for adding a new user to our active directory) and publish it on the share point.
At first I tought, that I could do this using Microsoft Forms, but it is not complex enough.
There Should be a DropDown control and depending on the selected item (company name) the next DropDown contorl (occupation) should offer specific items. At the end the form should be send by mail to our helpdesk.

My question is, which tool should I use to build the form?
Could you recommend me something? I am new to sharepoint, and I am not sure if I can use PHP or ASP.net?
And I am not sure if this is economically usefull for a simple form.
Maybe there is something lile Microsoft Forms, just a little bit more complex.
Thank you!

Comment: Try SPFx, or PowerApps form

Answer (score 1):

Can't use PHP of ASP.net as they are serverside, and SharePoint Online won't run this code unless hosted elsewhere and iframed into a page.

Simple would be MS Form with a Power Automate flow that detects new submission and sends email to help desk. You could then embed this MS Form on any page (sharepoint or teams e.t.c)

Or you could just use a SharePoint list form, and a Power Automate flow to once again detect new submission and sends emails.

PowerApps is really just a more capable MS Form, which it sounds like you don't need, so keep it simple to start with.